How to update Cache in vscode.MarkdownString?
I am developing an extension and I am using an Image in MarkdownString that's being cached by vscode
new vscode.MarkdownString(`<img src='${imgUri.path}'  width='200' height='200'/>`);

I have also tried creating images with different names and rendering, and it works prefectly.
But I don't want to create multiple files, so I am updating existing image without creating a new Image, for this reason, imgUri Path remains same. The problem is that the image is not being updated when MarkdownString is being displayed.
I even tried cache busting using query params
new vscode.MarkdownString(`<img src='${imgUri.path}?time=${new Date().getTime()}' alt="rendered preview" />`);

but it still doesn't update the markdown preview immediately. Is there a way to update the cache?
